# Azure Durable Functions: Can I use a startup.cs?

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a couple of functions that I want to refactor into a Azure Durable Function, where the orchestrator calls different ActivityFunctions (the previously seperate Azure Functions). The seperate functions use a startup where I configure dependency injection and some other configurations. 
Is it possible to use a startup class in a Durable Function scheme? I cannot find anything that seems to suggest this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp).

If it is not possible, what other alternatives are there, for example, to define database connection string and dependency injection?

Thnx

Comment: could you confirm if any of the solutions helps resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency Injection is possible in Durable Functions too.

Install and add reference to the following package from Nuget:

> `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Here's a working sample of Startup file with Dependency Injection done:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;


[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyDurableFunction.Startup))]

namespace MyDurableFunction
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var executioncontextoptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
                .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;
            var currentDirectory = executioncontextoptions.AppDirectory;
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT");

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
               .AddJsonFile($"settings.{environment}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables()
               .Build();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyBusinessService1>(sp =>
            {
                var secretFromAppSettings = config["secretKey"];
                var passwordFromAppSettings = config["secretPassword"];
                return new MyBusinessService1(secretFromAppSettings, passwordFromAppSettings);
            });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseHelper, DatabaseHelper>();

            builder.Services.AddLogging();
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to add the caveat that replacing the singleton `IConfiguration` is a pattern we do not recommend, as it replaces the configuration used by the Azure Functions host, including but not limited to the host.json. I recommend reading up on this issue and workarounds people have for it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4464)

Comment: @Sunny Sharma  Thanks for the elaborate answer. It works now for me, using your example.

Comment: thanks @ConnorMcMahon for the heads up! I've modified the code  and now it supports the configuration from "host.json" as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `Dependency Injection` similar to normal functions.

A complete example which I found in this [blog](https://peter.intheazuresky.com/2020/02/12/azure-functions-dependency-injection-the-forgotten-greatness/)